# Zabbix agent unable to detect PID of the running process

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, zabbix

I am getting some triggers that show process unavailable, but when I check on the host it runs fine. Here is how the expression for the Trigger is set:

```
{$hostname:proc.num[,,,/etc/alternatives/java].last()}=0
```

It seems to be working fine for some hosts, but some of them triggers process unavailable and sends the alert.

Affected host:

```
# ps ax | grep java
 1717 ?        Ssl  119:15 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --httpsCertificate=/var/lib/jenkins/.ssl/hostssl.crt --httpsPrivateKey=/var/lib/jenkins/.ssl/hostssl.key
```

Zabbix log:

```
  2000:20160901:081336.721 Starting Zabbix Agent [$hostname]. Zabbix 2.2.8 (revision 51174).
  2000:20160901:081336.721 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
  2002:20160901:081336.724 agent #0 started [collector]
  2004:20160901:081336.724 agent #2 started [listener #2]
  2005:20160901:081336.725 agent #3 started [listener #3]
  2006:20160901:081336.725 agent #4 started [active checks #1]
  2003:20160901:081336.725 agent #1 started [listener #1]
cat: /proc//status: No such file or directory
cat: /proc//status: No such file or directory
cat: /proc//status: No such file or directory
cat: /proc//status: No such file or directory
```

Host sending zabbix data properly:

```
# ps ax | grep java
 2472 ?        Ssl  1279:26 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Europe/Dublin -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --httpsCertificate=/var/lib/jenkins/.security/hostssl.crt --httpsPrivateKey=/var/lib/jenkins/.security/hostssl.key --httpsPort=8443
```

Zabbix log does not contain line cat: /proc//status: No such file or directory

In my understanding problem is that PID of the process is not discovered so it triggers an alert action.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this further so see why the zabbix agent cannot detect the PID of the running process on affected machines?

Comment: What operating system? Have you added a userparameter `proc.num`? If you check the processlist as the `zabbix` user, do you see those processes?

Comment: Linux(RHEL6 and 7), yes the parameter has been added and has worked fine and it does for majority of hosts. I can see the process as the zabbix user as well.

Comment: To clarify, you added a custom userparameter, overriding the built-in `proc.num` item key?

Comment: I am not sure what the difference is, but as I said in the description, there is a Trigger set that has this in the expression field: "{$hostname:proc.num[,,,/etc/alternatives/java].last()}=0" 
where $hostname is replaced by each host name of course and that has been working fine until recently.

Comment: Let's ignore triggers for now. To be completely sure, have you configured any item like this with a key `proc.num`? https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters - also, to reduce the amount of possibilities, do you run SELinux? Does it work if you temporarily disable SELinux?

Comment: yes there are multiple items configured for proc.num using the templates. SELinux is enabled on all machines and disabling it temporarily does not change the situation.

Comment: That didn't answer the question directly, but the suspicious part is `cat` in the logs - Zabbix doesn't do that. In your agent config file, do you have any uncommented `UserParameter` lines ?

Comment: sorry I confused it, the proc.num is used as built in parameter, I did not understand the difference properly. There are some Userparamaters configured, but nothing for proc.num[,,,/etc/alternatives/java], now that I understand better what UserParameter is, thinking of bash script that will override the failing proc.num built in parameter, however finding root cause would be preferred.

Comment: Your data looks a bit strange - there's also "Starting Zabbix Agent [$hostname]". The name looks wrong. If you run `ps ax | grep java` on the affected host as the `zabbix` user, do you see the process?

Comment: I got it resolved, it was SELinux in the end, problem was that disabling it did not change the situation straight away due to delays via proxy. Using zabbix_get it was visible straight away.

Comment: That sounds even more strange, as SELinux changes are not related to the configuration delay that Zabbix proxies introduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved now.

I used zabbix_get to get results from the zabbix agent. There I found that it cannot get any processes from the jenkins or any other non-zabbix user.

Googling brought me to this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1032691

Applying custom SELinux policy resolved the issue.